Hyper parameter tuning LSTM network on time series data
I am trying to train LSTM model (containing four LSTM layers (500 units each) and three droupouts and a fully connected output layer to do regression) on timeseries data. To start with, I tried to overfit (training data = testing data) the model on tiny data (few thousands of records, each of window 200). I was able to overfit the data when I start with tiny base learning rate (0.00005) (brown run in below graph). (I have discussed this in detail in another question here).
Now I am trying train this model on larger dataset (almost 300 times more records). I am observing following things:

I step down the learning rate in steps [0.00005, 0.000005, 0.0000005, 0.00000005]. (I know thats weirdly small learning rate. But, hey, am just trying it out. And I tried this for overfitting smaller data too and it works best. If I start from 0.005 I get very very bad predictions.). Also, I step down the LR only when there is no improvement in the validation loss for 7 consecutive epochs. As you can see in the pink colored run, I stepped down thrice (lr_group_0 chart). Still my validation loss did not decrease. and it plateued at very high loss (say in comparison with overfitting brown line in val_loss chart).

I early stopped training when there is no improvement in the validation loss after 25 epochs. This you can see in train_loss chart for pink line, which plateued at high training loss.



I have following guesses:

Do I need to start even with smaller LR say (0.000005) when training on larger data than when overfitting smaller data (0.00005) to get consistent validation and training loss?

Do I need to increase drop out probability significantly? For overfitting it was 0.1. Should I experiment with something like 0.25?

Do I need to increase model complexity, say six LSTM layers to improve training loss?


Am I correct with above? Also, what else can be done to improve the model peroformance?
